# How to digitally control the feedback of a switching regulator using digital pot? [updated]

Tags: power-supply, switching-regulator

I'm trying to build a digitally-controlled power supply using ordinary [LM2596](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiD3dCM4IH1AhXeSPEDHRNPD5IQFnoECAMQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.onsemi.com%2Fpdf%2Fdatasheet%2Flm2596-d.pdf&usg=AOvVaw1eYQ3hy5ZAab-Q92lNHLNR) or equivalent ICs and a microcontroller. the first approach was by using the DAC or a filtered PWM DAC the way [this](https://www.electroschematics.com/mp2307-digital-power-supply-module-teardown-analysis-part-1/) module does it:

[image: filtered PWM DAC]

The feedback of the regulator is set to a voltage using fixed resistors. another node of filtered PWM from microcontroller goes into feedback pin, forming some kind of voltage divider. so changing the PWM value forces the regulator to increase or decrease voltage.

### Big Problems with MCU intervention [section updated]

The problem with this design is that the response of software correction of output is a lot slower than the regulator. the software have to read ADC, average it, compare it to the desired value and change PWM value and check it again to see if it's good or not. while the regulator has "cycle by cycle" correction and it's analog response is a lot quicker. It is noticeable when the output capacitor is big or a big load is eventually connected to the output and voltage drops significantly. the MCU takes a longer time to correct its output. the settle time of the PWM DAC is negligible in this case. here is the code which I wrote to adjust the PWM value. it is in a loop beside an adc reading routine:

```
void CV_Control(void)
{
    if(curr_Voltage < des_Voltage -1500)                pwmVal-=350;
    else if(curr_Voltage < des_Voltage -1200)           pwmVal-=200;
    else if(curr_Voltage < des_Voltage -800)            pwmVal-=100;
    else if(curr_Voltage < des_Voltage -250)            pwmVal-=80;
    else if(curr_Voltage < des_Voltage -100)            pwmVal-=40;
    else if(curr_Voltage < des_Voltage -50)             pwmVal-=20;
    else if(curr_Voltage < des_Voltage -25)             pwmVal-=10;
    else if(curr_Voltage < des_Voltage -15)             pwmVal-=4;
    else if(curr_Voltage < des_Voltage)                 pwmVal-=1;

    if(curr_Voltage > des_Voltage +2000)                pwmVal+=350;
    else if(curr_Voltage > des_Voltage +1400)           pwmVal+=200;
    else if(curr_Voltage > des_Voltage +800)            pwmVal+=100;
    else if(curr_Voltage > des_Voltage +250)            pwmVal+=80;
    else if(curr_Voltage > des_Voltage +100)            pwmVal+=40;
    else if(curr_Voltage > des_Voltage +50)             pwmVal+=20;
    else if(curr_Voltage > des_Voltage +25)             pwmVal+=10;
    else if(curr_Voltage > des_Voltage +15)             pwmVal+=4;
    else if(curr_Voltage > des_Voltage +8)              pwmVal+=1;
    
    if(pwmVal > PWM_MAX)    pwmVal = PWM_MAX;
    else if(pwmVal < PWM_MIN)   pwmVal = PWM_MIN;
}
```

Which worked with light loads. **but failed in these cases**:

- the device turns on and the above routine tries to reach the default 12v output. a few moments later it is 12v. now I connect a load to the device. the voltage rapidly drops to a few volts and the above routine tries to set it again. it takes a few moments (between 200ms and 1s) to set it again at 12V. I think this correction routine is much faster when the internal analog error correction does it.
- I tried to "hasten" that routine by adding a few if-elses as you see. if the difference is big then jump bigger. in this case, sometimes happens that the voltage jumps above the desired value. for example if the current desired value is 5v and we set it to 18v, it may jump to 20v, then to 17v then 18.5v and finally settles at 18v. this thing gets worse when the output cap is big, like 2200uF.

### A digital pot seems better(?)

I had a few [MCP4017](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwj67aSd5YH1AhVyRPEDHREUDucQFnoECBYQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fww1.microchip.com%2Fdownloads%2Fen%2FDeviceDoc%2F22147a.pdf&usg=AOvVaw39UvS_m3a0dMF7J43wYTwc), 10k digital pots. They have I2C controlled, 128 steps from 0+75R to 10k+75R. the 75R is the fixed series resistance of the wiper. the maximum voltage of the digital pot is 5v (both the electronics and the resistor array). By using the digital pot, the output voltage correction is not done in the MCU anymore; the regulator itself corrects it which is a lot faster. **The question is, how can I place the digital pot into the feedback line of the LM2596 so that**:

- The 5v voltage limit is not reached so it won't get damaged
- The whole range of 128 steps are used. so the minimum and maximum output voltage of regulator is in 128 steps. the minimum and maximum are not constrained. despite the regulator can output from 1.25v to over 30v, the range of 2v to 20v or 24v would suffice

[image: typical application circuit of LM2596 from datasheet]

thanx for the time and knowledge.

Comment: I would say setting the FB voltage directly via PWM is much simpler. Just play with the time constant of the LP filter. Using a digipot wont really be faster. And with PWM you csn emply Delta Sigma modulation and greatly enhance the number of voltage levels

Comment: Even if you use a digital pot, doesn't the MCU still need to read the voltage, calculate the average, and then change the value of the pot? This doesn't sound much faster to me.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson when using a pot, the output voltage is strictly determined by the resistor divider value. for example the user wants 5V. the MCU calculates the resistor and sets it into pot. the MCU doesn't have to check the output at all because all corrections are done within the regulator.

Comment: There must be some minunderstanding about the circuit. The feedback does not go through the MCU. The MCU can just adjust the output voltage by altering the feedback, while the feedback from output keeps the voltage at the level which MCU sets it.

Comment: @tobalt When using a software solution, we are replacing an analog error amplifier+PWM controller with ~300Khz frequency, with an slower software solution. The digital pot doesn't replace the analog error correction. the MCU doesn't have to check anything.

Comment: @Justme yes. but in case of error correction, the MCU has a part in feedback. the regulator reacts fast but it won't be able to completely correct the output voltage. the MCU has to react too. which is slower. this difference complicates the correction process.

Comment: If you can calculate the desired value for the pot then you should be able to precalculate the appropriate PWM duty factor as well. I'm not sure we are clear about what the MCU is doing in this design.

Comment: Why are you so sure the MCU even wants to do feedback and correct the output voltage, what if the MCU only wants to set some output voltage and let the actual feedback handle it?

Comment: @Justme Then why there's an amplifier (11x + unity LM358 to the right of the red area)? how is it calculated then?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson I think I've chosen the wrong way then. I thought the MCU has to do cycle by cycle correction. still I dont know how to calculate the desired value of PWM DAC.

Comment: Please *edit your question* to reflect what you now know, so that the answers you want will make sense given the question.

Comment: Also, it is not clear how rapidly you want the power supply to respond -- if you're doing anything other than adjusting it and waiting a while for it to settle, then your use case is outside of what such power supplies are usually designed to handle -- you need to add that to your question.

Comment: @TirdadSadriNejad The 11x amplifier is for measuring current, the 0.1 ohm shunt converts current to voltage which is amplified.

Comment: _"When using a software solution, we are **replacing** an analog error amplifier+PWM controller with ~300Khz frequency, with an slower software solution."_ - you are? That's not what the example module does. Please show us your actual circuit.

Comment: @Justme sorry. the pin no. 17 is reading the voltage value with a 90k/10k divider.

Comment: @BruceAbbott my circuit is quite the same. It seems I was wrong about the way they calculate the output voltage. I thought they increase or decrease PWM blindly till they get the desired output voltage.

Comment: @TirdadSadriNejad I never claimed anything else. Pin 17 is used for reading output voltage like you said. Pin 15 is used for reading output current like I said. I was not talking about pin 17.

Answer (score 1):

For the purposes of this sort of computation, a switching regulator acts like an ideal op-amp with an internal node supplying the feedback voltage (0.925V in the case of your MP2307) to the \$V_+\$ input of the op-amp, and the \$V_{fb}\$ pin is the \$V_-\$ node.

So take the essential bits of your circuit, and reduce them to an equivalent, where \$V_{pwm}\$ is understood to be the *average* of the PWM voltage:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNuPki.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Note that I'm just paying attention to DC here, not settling time, so I'm ignoring the capacitors.

To get started, you just need to:

- Calculate \$V_{fb}\$ as a function of \$V_{pwm}\$ and \$V_{out}\$
- Solve for \$V_{out}\$ as a function of \$V_{pwm}\$ and \$V_{fb}\$, with \$V_{fb}\$ set to the chip's feedback voltage level

From there, you can determine the resistor values you need to get the voltage ranges you want.  Note that with all of this it is a *very good idea* to back this calculation up with simulation, because you're messing with the gain of a control loop, and switching supplies are nonlinear devices.  You want to make sure that the loop is stable when you're done.

I'm going to take shortcuts here, leaving it as your job to figure out the basic circuit analysis.

Let \$R_{eq}\$ be the parallel resistance of \$R_5\$ and \$R_6\$; \$R_{eq} = \frac{R_6}{R_5 + R_6}(10 \mathrm {k\Omega}) = 9375 \Omega\$.  The Thevenin equivalent voltage of \$V_{out}\$, \$R_5\$ and \$R_6\$ is \$\frac{R_5}{R_5 + R_6}\$ (\$\frac{1}{16}\$).

Then
$$
V_{fb} = \frac{
\frac{R_5}{R_5 + R_6}\left(R_4 + R_{eq}\right)V_{out} +
\left(R_1 + R_2 + R_3\right)V_{pwm}
}
{R_1 + R_2 + R_3 + R_4 + R_{eq}} \tag 1$$

Solve for \$V_{out}\$:

$$
V_{out} = \frac{
  \left( R_1 + R_2 + R_3 + R_4 + R_{eq} \right)V_{fb} -
  \left(R_1 + R_2 + R_3\right)V_{pwm}
}
{R_4 + R_{eq}} \tag 2
$$

Note that for the circuit as given, this is

$$
V_{out} = \frac{
  \left( 51 \mathrm{k\Omega} + 9375\Omega + 71\mathrm{k\Omega} \right)V_{fb} -
  \left( 71\mathrm{k\Omega}\right)V_{pwm}
}
{51 \mathrm{k\Omega} + 9375\Omega} \tag 3
$$

For the circuit as given you can use (3) to determine what PWM setting to use for a given output voltage.  If you want to guarantee your limits on the output voltage, you can use (2) to find a better set of resistances.  I suggest that you leave \$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$ alone unless you also want to change how fast the circuit responds, and confine yourself to adjusting \$R_3\$ and \$R_5\$, assuming that works for you.

Comment: It seems I was wrong about the way they calculate the output voltage. I thought they increase or decrease PWM blindly till they get the desired output voltage.

Comment: @TirdadSadriNejad what you describe would be closed-loop voltage control and is entirely practical. It has the advantage of being as accurate as the ADC but slow due to the need of measuring the output voltage and running the PWM in a control loop. The open-loop control with pre-calculated PWM is immediate but can be a little inaccurate due to resistor tolerance and other small tolerances.

Comment: The equation (3) gives an output voltage of 2v for Vpwm = 0, and an output voltage of 1v when the Vpwm = Vfb = 0.925. for maximum Vpwm = 1.7v, the equation gives a zero output. this is in contrast with the provided output voltage of 0~16.5v for the module.